# how can i do background video width 100% and height 100vh

Tags: css, html5-video

I want to do background video. And width must be 100vw. And height also 100vh. Height can be cut, but not deformed. Video must save itself proportions.

Comment: Just create a `<video>` element and style it with `position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;`

Comment: Thanks, it's work.

Comment: Glad to help. I added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `<video>` element and set the `min-width` and `min-height` attributes to 100%.

Example:

```css
#video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video id="video">
  <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```